# Factorial using pointers in C program

Tags: c

I want to create a program to find the factorial of a number also I want to make it using pointers.

I have tried to make a program but it is not giving the factorial of the number . Can anybody explains me why ?

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int fact(int* num, int* n)
{
    for ((*n) = 1; (*n) <= (*num); (*n)++)
    {
        *n = (*n)*(*num);
    }
}

int main()
{
    int num, n;
    printf("Write the number to take factorial \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    fact(&num, &n);
    printf("Factorial = %d", n);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: I salute you for wanting to write non-trivial programs. But you really should learn how [to debug your programs](https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-programs/) instead of appealing to StackOverflow to do it for you.

Comment: Why do you want to use pointers here? Why isn't the loop variable `n` local to the function `fact`?

Comment: @MOehm I want to learn pointers

Comment: Compile your program with all warnings and debug info (`gcc -Wall -Wextra -g` with [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/)...). Improve it to get no warnings. **Use the debugger**  `gdb` to run it step by step and understand its behavior, and `valgrind` to hunt memory leaks. Repeat till satisfied.

Comment: @Koolman: The normal way of learning pointers is to build a *linked-list* of an arbitrary type.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

As you are using int function it must contain some return value. If you make following changes it runs perfectly.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int fact(int *num, int *n)
{
    long long unsigned int fact = 1;
    for ((*n) = 1; (*n) <= (*num); (*n)++)
    {
        fact = fact * (*n);
    }
    return fact;
}

int main()
{
    int num, n;
    long long unsigned int b;
    printf("Write the number to take factorial \n");
    scanf("%d", &num);
    b = fact( &num, &n);
    printf("Factorial = %llu", b);
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Aside from your not checking the return value of `scanf`, and your not guarding against the vulnerability of `int` overflow, this is nice.

Comment: ok .I changed it to long long unsigned it.So it will work for more numbers.

Comment: You might want to change the function return type too, and the calling site.

Comment: Calculating a `long long unsigned int` and then returning it as an `int` is counter-productive unless `sizeof(long long unsigned int) == sizeof(int)` which is seldom the case.

Answer (score 1):

`*n=(*n)*(*num);` is changing the value of the counting variable used in the `for` loop!

Whilst this is perfectly legal in C, it's leading to the incorrect answer.

You also don't return a value explicitly from `fact` despite it having a non-`void` return type. That's *undefined behaviour*.

Note also that the range for an `int` can be as small as -32767 to +32767, which only allows for 7! or lower. Consider using a `long long` type instead.

Comment: `(*n)*(*num)` - All those asterisks make my eyes hurt. (Not a judgement of the answer)

Comment: Does `*n * *num` finish them off completely ;-) ?

Comment: I just had to open my mouth and make matters worse... :)

Comment: okay , I have replaced in fact by void fact . but then also it is not working  properly

Comment: But what about the changes to `*n=(*n)*(*num);`? Really it would be simplest to get it working with non-pointers first, then introduce the pointers secondarily.

Comment: I have written them as *n=*n**num;

Comment: Can you not see that doing this breaks the counting variable in the `for` loop? You need to get your debugger out now; there's not much more I can do.

Comment: @Koolman Use a separate loop variable. `i` seems to be popular.  `*n` is already being used for other things.

Answer (score 1):

Correct me if I am wrong,  but I think the logic itself is incorrect in your attempt :

```
for ((*n) = 1; (*n) <= (*num); (*n)++)
    {
        *n = (*n)*(*num);
    }
```

You are using the counting variable ('*n' in this case) for purpose of storing the result. If you check the flow the loop will end after first iteration then increment it giving you the value of (*num + 1).

A good modification for your fact function could be :

```
void fact(int* num, int* n)
{
    int counter;
    *n=1;
    for (counter = 2 ; counter <= (*num) ; counter++)
    {
        *n = (*n)*(counter);
    }
}
```

Can't see a reason to keep the return type of the function as int if you are using call by reference for the result as well.

As in response to answer given by '@nikhil biijjala' , I can't understand your reason to pass the pointer (*n) in the first place.All that pointer does is works as a local counter for the loop.

As in case of large integers you can add limits to input or use long long.

Answer (score 0):

```
C++ Version:

#include <iostream>
int abc(int *a);
int main()
{
    int a,fact;
    int *ptr;
    std::cout << "Enter a:"<< std::endl;
    std::cin >> a;
    ptr= &a;
    fact=*ptr;
    while(*ptr!=1)
    {   
        fact = fact * abc(ptr); 
    }
    std::cout << "Factorial is : <<" << fact << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
int abc(int *a)
{
    *a=*a-1;
    return *a;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include<stdio.h>

int facto(int *);
int main()
{

    int factorial, v;
    printf("Enter the value : ");
    scanf("%d", &v);
    factorial = facto(&v);

    printf("The factorial of %d is %d.\n", v, factorial);
}

int facto(int *p)
{
    int c;
    c = *p - 1;
    if (*p == 1)
        return 1;
    else
        return (*p) * (facto(&c));
}
```